# VB6 recordset code to VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, vb6, recordset

I am updating someone elses old code from a VB6 windows application to a VB.Net web application. I understand the old code, but I am not sure how I would translate it to .Net recordsets.

```
myStoredProcedure = "sp_WritevPayrollCurrent"
        myCurrentPast = "'N'"
    myStoredProcedure = "sp_ObtainSubClassID"
       myClassName = "Payroll Major"
       mySubClassName = "New Hire"
       Set rs = TgetReadResultsetWithParms(myClassName, mySubClassName, (myStoredProcedure))
```

Also, I am not sure what will happen with "myStoredProcedure" being declared twice or could that be an error?

The TgetReadResultsetWithParms function is as follows (some Cases redacted to free up space):

```
Dim en As rdoEnvironment
Dim cn As rdoConnection
Dim rq As rdoQuery

 rdoDefaultCursorDriver = rdUseServer
'open a connection to the tstdbexecutive database using DSNless connections
Set en = rdoEnvironments(0)
Set cn = connectionstring stuff here
Select Case myStoredProcedure
    'create reusable rdoQuery and Call SQL server stored procedure.
    Case "sp_ObtainClassID"
        Set rq = cn.CreateQuery("", "{call " & cstDatabaseName & ".dbo.sp_ObtainClassID(?)}")
    Case Else
        Set rq = cn.CreateQuery("", "{call " & cstDatabaseName & ".dbo." & myStoredProcedure & "(?)}")
End Select
'set the input argument value for the store procedure.
rq(0) = myParm1
'open the Resultset and pass it back to calling procedure
Set TgetReadResultsetWithParm = rq.OpenResultset(rdOpenKeyset, rdConcurReadOnly)
```

Comment: What database engine are you using? MS Access? Sql Server? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

The VB6 code is using `Remote Data Objects`. I think you will have to read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733584%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) to understand what the VB6 is doing, and then rewrite in VB.Net using ADO.Net to achieve the same functionality. AFAIK there is no handy cheat-sheet which shows how RDO compares with ADO.Net, unfortunately. There are [some](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973217.aspx) for ADO-ADO.Net.

Alternatively you *could* add a reference to Remote Data Objects in your .Net project - you can use COM objects in .Net - and then use the same code. If there is a large amount of the old code, this could be a pragmatic way to make the task more manageable, although it makes the code harder to understand for other programmers who would probably be used to ADO.Net. It's better to rewrite if you can afford to.